# ASP .NET ProcessModel configuration

Tags: asp.net, processmodel

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx) documentation in MSDN for ProcessModel, the autoConfig=true sets the following attributes in accordance with this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=821268) article:

maxWorkerThreads, maxIoThreads, minFreeThreads, minLocalRequestFreeThreads, maxConnection

To verify this setting, I have a sample web application in ASP .NET 3.5 having the following code in the page_load event:

```
        int w, c;

        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out w, out c);

        // Write the numbers of minimum threads
        Response.Write("Min: " + string.Format("{0}, {1}", w, c));

        w=0;
        c = 0;

        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out w, out c);

        Response.Write(" Max: " + string.Format("{0}, {1}", w, c));

        Response.Write(" Maxconnections: " + ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);

        Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
        ConfigurationSectionGroup secGrp = conf.SectionGroups["system.web"];
        ConfigurationSection sec = secGrp.Sections["httpRuntime"];
        Response.Write(" httpruntime settings: " + sec.ElementInformation.Properties["minFreeThreads"].Value + ", " +
                                                    sec.ElementInformation.Properties["minLocalRequestFreeThreads"].Value);

        Response.Flush();
```

I get the following output when I run the page with autoConfig set to false first and then set to true:

autoConfig=false: Min: 2, 2 Max: 40, 40 Maxconnections: 10 httpruntime settings: 8, 4

autoConfig=true: Min: 2, 2 Max: 200, 200 Maxconnections: 24 httpruntime settings: 8, 4

autoConfig=false works as expected and the default values can be seen in the output, however the output when set to true suprised me a bit:

1. It does set the maxWorkerThreads and maxIoThreads attributes correctly and hence the output of 200 (100x2 on a dual core CPU).
2. However, it doesn't seem to set the minWorkerThreads attribute which as per the KB should be: minWorkerThreads =  maxWorkerThreads/2
3. Also, according to the MSDN documentation setting autoConfig=true does set the minFreeThreads and minLocalRequestFreeThreads attribute to values recommended in the KB, but that doesn't seem to be the case either. I get the default values of 8 and 4.

I am a bit confused, any ideas as to what's happening here? Have i got the sample wrong or something?

Comment: I'm trying to improve my webservice throughput (currently getting 100% CPU load for only a few users) and I ran into the exact same issue. I get 20 for MaxWorkerThreads when AutoConfig is enabled.

Comment: I am running ASP.NET 3.5 app in IIS6 on dual core machine and I am getting same results as you.

Comment: Something amiss, not sure what? We ended up tinkering the settings manually in web.config after setting the AutoConfig attribute to false!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are dealing with the same kind of logic below:

[WCF 4: Higher Default Throttling Settings for WCF Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx)

In WCF 4, we have revised the default values of these settings so that people don’t have to change the defaults in most cases. Here are the main changes:

·        MaxConcurrentSessions: default is **100 * ProcessorCount**

·        MaxConcurrentCalls: default is **16 * ProcessorCount**

·        MaxConcurrentInstances: default is the total of the above two, which follows the same pattern as before.