# Processmodel Configuration in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, machine.config

To configure Process model for Asp.Net I have seen,

1. [asp-net-processmodel-configuration-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939230/asp-net-processmodel-configuration-optimization)
2. [asp-net-processmodel-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310719/asp-net-processmodel-configuration)

This does not give me clear information and im having a scenario-

> i want to configure a custom processmodel for specific ASP.NET
>   Webservice (i will put it in a separate App pool if needed) but other
>   webservice/site in the IIS should use the default processmodel
>   configuration that is exist in machine.config.

My question is,

> Is it possible to configure a processmodel in web.config for specific
>   ASP.NET web service?
>
> if possible then is there any issue should i have to keep in mind and
>   also does the other application in the IIS will have problem while
>   using default config of processmodel in Machine.Config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [processModel configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it is not possible to configure it for an individual application in IIS.

> The processModel section can be set only within the Machine.config
>   file and affects all ASP.NET applications that are running on the
>   server.

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use the [httpRuntime configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. but the first link i have provided in the question, bzlm says it is possible to configure processmodel in web.config. you can see.

Comment: MSDN explicitly states it is not possible. And besides, it would not make much sense either, since ASP.NET applications in IIS don't have their own process. They execute inside an AppDomain. So configuration at the process level doesn't make sense in web.config, since it could affect other applications in the same process (w3wp.exe) and/or same application pool.